# generate unique hash from strings composed of english smaller case letters of length upto 4

Tags: string, hash, hashmap, key-value, alphabet

I want to generate unique hash from strings composed of English smaller case letters of length upto 4, so that I can store those unique hashes in my has map (STL unordered map)

For example, strings can be "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "mnop", "nbog", "puya", "p", "lk" and so on...

Can we generate unique hashes from these string(s)?